# Spring HandlerInterceptor mapping with annotations

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

Good day.
I got a spring mvc application and 2 controllers inside. 
First controller (PublicController) can process requests from all users, Second (PrivateController) can only process authorized users.

So I implemented two Handler Interceptor`s

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="webapp.base.package")
public class WebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LoggerInterceptor());
        registry.addInterceptor(new AccessInterceptor());
    }

}
```

I need my `LoggerInterceptor` to handle all controller's requests, and my `AccessInterceptor` to handle only `PrivateController`'s requests. 
I must map `Interceptors` to `Controllers` with annotations

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just solve it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="webapp.base.package")
public class WebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LoggerInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");;
        registry.addInterceptor(new AccessInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/private/**");;
    }

}
```

Comment: If I use this solution in my springboot application it breaks everything.

Comment: @LNT springboot will break because of the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. This turns off springboot's default mvc configurations. Just remove this annotation and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, when I use your way, it worked. But the interceptor executed twice. And I found another way to do this.

```
    @Bean
    public MappedInterceptor interceptor() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(null, new String[]{"/","/**/*.js", "/**/*.html", "/**/*.css"}, new LogInterceptor());
    }
```