# Is it possible to set interceptor with annotation in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to stay declarative, convention-base and XML-less.

So, I have no `web.xml`, and I have no context configuration XMLs. Unfortunately, Google is spammed with old-fashion `Spring` examples and it is impossible to find modern answer.

My question is: is it possible to declare interceptor with annotations in Spring? Apparently it would be possible to do the same way as it done with controllers (controller class is annotated with `@Controller` and it's methods -- with `@RequestMapping`).

The best way I found is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706896/258483

Unfortunately, it is not declarative.

Comment: I just interesting, how did you run your spring-mvc application without web.xml? How did you register DispatcherServlet in servlet container?

Comment: I don't know :) I am experimenting with Spring Boot. It can run under embedded Tomcat or produce conventional WAR.

Comment: Actually, Spring has to load context from somewhere. It has much of context loaders, but two most common ways are load it from Xml or Java-based configurations. Annotation created just to make configuration lighter, and make developer's job more convenient. So I afraid configuration (xml or java-based) can not be replaced by annotation totally.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java configuration and the `@Configuration` annotation it looks like you create an interceptor and register it as described [here](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-handlerinterceptor-annotation-example-webmvcconfigureradapter). It's not as simple as annotating a class as an interceptor but may still adhere to your stipulations.

EDIT:

> In java configuration class, we need to extend
>   WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. To add our interceptor, we override
>   WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. addInterceptors() method. Find the code
>   snippet.
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
>     registry.addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor());
>     registry.addInterceptor(new TransactionInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/person/save/*");
> }
> ```